# Как добавить href ссылку в таб и при нажатии на кнопку переходить на неё

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть блок с табами и js, как изменить что-бы можно было сделать переход не по ссылке, а с помощью кнопки, button, нужно изменить немного js но как это сделать?

```js
var link = $(".st-right");
$(".st-tabs").on("click", "span", function() {
  link.attr("href", "http://www.ya.ru/");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="st-left">
    <div class="st-tabs">
      <span class="active">TAB1</span>
      <span>TAB2</span>
      <span>TAB3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <a class="st-right" href="/test1.html">Еще<span class="fa fa-align-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

создай баттон внутри тега `<a>`, зачем мучиться?

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com"><button>button</button></a>
```

если все же хочешь помучиться то вот еще способы:

```js
function hrefto(adres) {
window.location.href = adres;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hrefto('https://www.google.com')">href</button>
```

а также можно сделать любой элемент кликабельным и перенаправляющим

```js
function hrefto(adres) {
window.location.href = adres;
}
```

```css
div {
cursor: pointer;
}

img {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="hrefto('https://www.google.com')">example1</div>

<img src="https://www.onmsft.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/stackoverflow.png" 
onclick="hrefto('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1414779/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-href-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%91/1415175#1415175')">
```